# Front-end Ajax File Upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, uploads

I'm working on a project where registred users can upload file to a specific post type. For a more fluid navigation, I'm making this whole part with Ajax, so the page never reloads.
However I'm having a hard time trying to make a `<input type="file">` work.
Here's my code so far:

### Markup

```
<?php
    // Start Loop and current meta of the post
?>
<form class="update_post" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
    <label for="new_value_1_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Value 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="new_value_1_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" id="new_value_1_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" value="" required>
    <label for="new_value_2_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">Value 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="new_value_2_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" id="new_value_2_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" value="" required>
    <label for="file_upload_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">File Upload</label>
    <input type="text" name="file_upload_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" id="file_upload_for_<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" value="" required>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button1 submit_update_post" value="Send">
    <div class="progress_bar"></div>    
</form>
<?php
    // End Loop
?>
```

### jQuery

```
$(".update_post").submit(function(){
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "url_to_php_file",
        data: formData, 
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            // Show a loader animation
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // Hide the loader animation and update the info
        },
        error: function() {
            // Display error message
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

### php

```
$post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
$value_1 = $_POST['new_value_1_for_'.$post_id.''];
$value_2 = $_POST['new_value_2_for_'.$post_id.''];

// Update the Post Meta
update_post_meta($post_id, 'value_1', $value_1);
update_post_meta($post_id, 'value_2', $value_2);

// Upload the file
$file_upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES['file_upload_for_'.$post_id.'']['name'], null, file_get_contents($_FILES['file_upload_for_'.$post_id.'']['tmp_name']));
    if (isset($file_upload['error']) && $file_upload['error'] != 0) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("' . $file_upload['error'] .'");
        </script>';
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'file_upload', "");
    }
    else {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'file_upload', $file_upload);
    }

$file_uploaded = get_post_meta($post_id, 'file_upload', true );

// Output
$array = array(
    "value_1"       => $value_1,
    "value_2"       => $value_2,
    "file_url"      => $file_uploaded['url'],
);

print json_encode($array);
```

Everything but the file upload works.
Is there something I'm missing?
Thank you so much.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use wordpress functions (eg. update_post_meta) in a php file that doesn't know those functions exist. You either need to to include parts of wordpress in the php file (see wp-load.php), or do ajax the wordpress way -> http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Most people will recommend doing the wordpress way.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your reply!
I'm so sorry, I have not stated, but I have loaded the wordpress functions inside the external php file. I was trying to avoid too much lines in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to upload

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) )  {

                    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );  
}

if($_FILES['file']['name'] != '') {

                         $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file'];

                         $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );

                         $movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides );

                         if ( $movefile && ! isset( $movefile['error'] ) ) {

                            $file_url = $movefile['url'];

                            $file_url = $movefile['file'];
                         } 
}
```

if you need to limit the file types to download, you need to change the line

```
$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false);
```

on

```
$mimes = [
            'wmv' => 'video/x-ms-wmv',
            'wmx' => 'video/x-ms-wmx',
            'wm' => 'video/x-ms-wm',
            'avi' => 'video/avi',
            'divx' => 'video/divx',
            'flv' => 'video/x-flv',
         ];


$upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false, 'mimes' => $mimes );
```

full list of mime types

```
print_r(get_allowed_mime_types());
```